# Is it possible to deploy a Node server with tensorflow.js on CENTOS 7.8?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, centos7

I've been trying to deploy my node server with tensorflow.js but when requiring @tensorflow/tfjs-node keep getting the same error. Already tried everything but nothing seems to be working. Is it possible that the issue is related to a compatibility problem with CentOs?

[server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pD30.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUvlI.png)

[output when running server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhexO.png)

[vps os](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKoy1.png)

Comment: Which version of node.js are you using? Please provide the output of node -v

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @andypotato Node version 10.22.0.

Comment: And @trax  the error is shown in the "output when running server.js" image. And the error occurs when starting the server. I have no other tensorflow.js code inside server.js than the one in the "server.js" image